# F6 toggles brightness level in xcode instead of stepping

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode

I'm using xcode on a macbook. I want to debug my code. When I press F6 to step over, it increases brightness in combinaison with F5 which decreases it. I have to press FN+F6 to properly step. How can I drop the FN requirement?

In xcode everything seems configured correctly in preferences->keybingdings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In system preferences -> keyboard, check that the option is turned on for 'Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys'